# Distribution of Photon Inter-arrival Times

Tags: photons, probability

In case of a coherent light source (eg. laser beam) the number of photons counted in a given time interval can be modeled as a Poisson distribution. From the theory of Poisson processes, it is well known that the inter-arrival time has an exponential distribution.

In case of a narrow band Gaussian thermal light source with photon bunching, [I have read that](https://books.google.com/books?id=-anzBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=optical%20narrow%20band%20gaussian%20fields&source=bl&ots=g7VBUTgQjc&sig=ePMx31ZRM7Hu2qyWSbSo104SfGk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6v5Og7cfTAhUF5IMKHarCD0UQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=optical%20narrow%20band%20gaussian%20fields&f=false) the number of photons in a time interval T follows Bose-Einstein statistics (i.e. a geometric distribution) where the probability of counting $m$ photons is given by:
$$
P(m)=\frac{\bar{n}^m}{(1+\bar{n})^{m+1}}
$$
where $\bar{n}$ is the average number of photons in time $T$. Note that this is independent of the time interval $T$ due to the underlying assumption that the time interval $T \ll1/$bandwidth of the light source.

My question is, how do I obtain the inter-arrival time distribution in this case?

Comment: Please mention the explicit form of the probability function for photon counts.

Comment: @Deep I added the probability mass function for photon counts.

Comment: Can you please point me to the derivation of this equation? Or even better, include this derivation in your question?